# Android Custom Spinner Layout

Tags: android, spinner

I create a custom layout for a spinner and is working well when i am selecting some options on the spinner. But when you select the item the layout is not working.

I paste a image on the left is the spinner dropdown so you can select something and in the right is the spinner when you have selected an option.

As you can see in the right the custom layout is not workin.

[image: Spinner custom layout]

And my custom layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/colorblanco"
    android:background="@color/colorfondosuperior"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Any idea how to apply the custom layout to the spinner when is not in dropdown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

custom layout's `TextView` has has id @+id/textview

```
TextView spinnerdata =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      spinnerdata.setText(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, both are a spinners but the left one is clicked and the right one isnt clicked to show how is showed. There is not a textview on that image. What i want to change is the color of the text of the spinner when is not in DropDownView.